# S3 to store static contents only, or together host the presentation tier of the 3-tiers architecture?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, presentation

As we normally know the 3-tiers architecture: **Presentation layer(Web Server), Logic tier(App Server), and Data layer(Database).**

And we know the S3 in AWS is not only providing the capability to store the static contents, but **also can act the role of presentation layer(Web Server)**.

So there are two options in my mind that:

1. S3 as content holder, EC2 act as web server: put all static contents(like images for this case) in S3, build web server by EC2 instance, upload web pages(the link of the images points to S3, the dynamic portion points to the app server by reverse proxy)
2. S3 as both content holder and web server, but need to work with App server like presentation layer web server do

My questions are:

1. Is it reasonable for the above option 2? (The case is not a static web hosting)
2. If reasonable, what's the difference between option 1 and 2?
3. If not reasonable, why S3 is able to host static web site, but can't act as the presentation layer(web server) of a multi-tier web site(static+dynamic)?

Comment: You can only host static content on S3. Are you asking why S3 can't be used to host dynamic content? Your question is full of generalizations which makes it difficult to provide an exact answer. What specific technologies are you wanting to use to build your web application?

Comment: Thank you Mark, the question is not asking S3 to host dynamic content, instead, the dynamic content will be on EC2. Normally if I host static contents on EC2 as the web tier, I need to setup reverse-proxy as the handler to forward back to back-end EC2(host the dynamic ones), but if the static goes to S3, is it possible/reasonable to do the reverse-proxy back to my dynamic contents on EC2?

Comment: Where would you be running the reverse proxy? S3 doesn't have that capability. To accomplish this you would probably want to create a CloudFront distribution with multiple sources.

Comment: Mark, yes, that's I was trying to ask. So if this is the case, the S3 only used for static files(instead of static web site), but the page(or let's say the web site) should be hosted in EC2 in order to facility the reverse-proxy by the Apache.